# Angularjs fastest way to find next td vertically in a big table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a special grid directive that has lots of rows and can't be paginated.
Each td has a text input, on "Enter Key press" the input below it should be focused(the input in the td in the next row same column).

This is what i am using right now :

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {//enter
    input.blur();
    var row = td.parent();
    var nextRow = row.next();
    if (nextRow.length)
        nextRow.children().eq(td.index()).find('input').focus();
    else {
        row.parent()//tbody
            .children().eq(0)//first row
            .children().eq(td.index() + 1)//next column
            .find('input').focus();
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this? maybe with pure js or full jquery ?

Comment: In which way is this version slow? Laggy UI?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes the changes happens with delay when i have about 1000 rows.

Comment: Try a virtualized list then.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv whats that? would appreciate if you can provide a sample or reference

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv tanx 4 the links, i already did some research about it, i am going to implement it. I told this to my boss and he loved it, it seems to be the best option. this is part of a big special data entry grid and it solves lots of my performance issues .+1